# Formality of writing proofs on, "If and only if," or similar statements.

Tags: proof-writing

Often in lectures when the lecturer proves a statement , $A \iff B$, they start off with writing ("$\Longrightarrow$") then proceeds to prove that $B$ follows from $A$ and then, ("$\Longleftarrow$") for the opposite. I understand this is usually for clarity during the lectures, but I was wondering if this was also a common practice within mathematical writing? A similar thing can be said for set equalities that is I often see ("$\subset$") and ("$\supset$"), sometimes without parenthesis.

Comment: I don't see this very often in papers (though I am sure that I have seen it once or twice), but I doubt that anyone is going to stop you if you include it.  I also don't really think that this is on-topic here---really, this is a discussion that you should have with your advisor (assuming that you are writing a thesis of some sort), or the editor of whatever journal you are submitting your paper to.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't realise this was off topic, I just saw other questions talking about formality in proof writing so I thought it was okay, I can delete it if prompted to. On another note, I was just curious and not currently writing any paper (still in my second year).

Comment: It is rare that an "if and only if" proof can be made just using $\iff$ equivalences. The rule is more often that the "if" and the "ony if" parts are proven separately.